# How to add a description of words from text to an array, to an array key by passing words?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, text, explode

I have a book in which there are many words in this form:

```
ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукан- дом, латифбадан.
FБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, даст- гоњи обпошї.
БАНЉИР انجير آب обе, ки дар он анљири ќоќ
ва хушкро мељӯшонанд ва он хусусияти
табобатї дорад.
ӮББАДАЛ بدل آب муовизаи об, табдили об.
ТББАНД بند آب 1. он ки дар пеши об банд ё
дарѓот месозад. 2. банд, дарѓот.
ОББАР بر آب 1. он ки об мебарад, обкаш, маш- коб. 2. маљ. маъшуќ, ки тавассути њуснаш
обрўи ошиќи худро зери хавфи коҳиш
мегузорад. 3. тех. облўла, лўлаи обрасонї, ќубури обгузар.
ЗББАРДОР آببردار 1. обро ба худ гиранда, он
чи зиёд об талаб мекунад, обталаб; биринљи
оббардор. 2. ниг. обчинак.
ҚББАРДОРЇ آببرداري 1. обкашї, машкобї. 2.
об бардоштани чизе (мас., биринљ).
ҶББАРДОШТА برداشته آب рахнае, ки бо фишор
ё љараёни об ба амал омадааст, оббурда, об- шуста (мас., дар банди об ё замин).
ӢББАРО برا آب љои баромади об, љое, ки об аз
он љорї мешавад.
ЪББАЊО بها آب кит. музди об, пули об.
ӢББО اآب нидо, лањљ. изњори тааљљуб ва афсўс.
РББОЗ باز آب шиновар, ѓаввос, обдон, оббур.
ОББОЗИДОРЇ بازيداري آبоббозї доштан
(мас., кўдакро, беморро ва ѓ.)
ОББОЗЇ آببازي шиноварї, оббурї; оббозї кар- дан ба об даромадан ва шустушў кардан, шино кардан.
СББУР بر آب 1. ниг. оббоз. 2. бахши пеши поя- њои пулу купрукњо муќобили љараёни об, ки
нўгтез буда, мављњои обро таќсим карда, фишори обро бар сутуни пояњо суст мекунад.
ОББУРДА برده آب 1. љои рахна карда хокро
шуста бурдаи об, љои обшустаи дарѓот. 2.
љар, љарї, сой.
ҲББУРЇ بري آب обро бурида гузаштан, шиноварї.
ОБВАРЗ ورز آب обдон, оббоз, шиновар.
ДБВАРЗЇ ورزي آب оббозї, шиноварї.
УБГАЗ آبگز осебдида ва зарардида бар асари
муддати зиёд зери об мондан.
ОБГАРДИШ گردش آب 1. хамгашт (-и дарё). 2.
гирдоб. 3. таѓйири мусбат ва ё манфии таб- дили иќлим ба саломатї; нотобї бар асари
табдили иќлим. 4. кит. тезрафтор, хушраф- тор.
```

As you see all the words that you need to add to the key of the array are written with large letters. By passing these words to the array key, I want to add all the description of these words to the array. How can I do this through regular expression?

The approximate result looks as follows:

```
$wordsDescription = array(
    "ОБАНДОМ" => "آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукан- дом, латифбадан.",
    "FБАФКАН" => "آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, даст- гоњи обпошї.",
    "БАНЉИР" => "نجير آب обе, ки дар он анљири ќоќ ва хушкро мељӯшонанд ва он хусусияти табобатї дорад.",
    "ӮББАДАЛ" => "بدل آب муовизаи об, табдили об.",
    "ТББАНД" => "بند آب 1. он ки дар пеши об банд ё дарѓот месозад. 2. банд, дарѓот.",
    "ОББАР" => "بر آب 1. он ки об мебарад, обкаш, маш- коб. 2. маљ. маъшуќ, ки тавассути њуснаш обрўи ошиќи худро зери хавфи коҳиш мегузорад. 3. тех. облўла, лўлаи брасонї, ќубури обгузар.",
    .................
    "ОБГАРДИШ" => "گردش آب 1. хамгашт (-и дарё). 2. гирдоб. 3. таѓйири мусбат ва ё манфии таб- дили иќлим ба саломатї; нотобї бар асари табдили иќлим. 4. кит. тезрафтор, хушраф- тор."
);
```

If possible then the second array with the second result

```
$wordsTranslate = array(
    "ОБАНДОМ" => "آباندام",
    "FБАФКАН" => "آبافكن",
    ....................,
    "ОБГАРДИШ" => "گردش آب"
);
```

Comment: Using this regular.expr I removed hyphens in my text: `preg_replace('~-\R~', '', $text);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may capture the words with the descriptions with

```
~^(\p{Lu}+)\h+(.*(?:\R(?!\p{Lu}+\h).*)*)~mu
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/diLvEz/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to the `m` modifier)
- `(\p{Lu}+)` - 1 or more uppercase Unicode letters
- `\h+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespace
- `(.*(?:\R(?!\p{Lu}+\h).*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\R(?!\p{Lu}+\h).*)*` - 0 or more sequences of

    - `\R(?!\p{Lu}+\h)` - a line break sequence not followed with 1+ uppercase Unicode letters and 1 horizontal whitespace
    - `.*` - the rest of the line.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/kFFDC1):

```
$s = "ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукан- дом, латифбадан.\nFБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, даст- гоњи обпошї.\nБАНЉИР انجير آب обе, ки дар он анљири ќоќ\nва хушкро мељӯшонанд ва он хусусияти\nтабобатї дорад.\nӮББАДАЛ بدل آب муовизаи об, табдили об.";
$re = '~^(\p{Lu}+)\h+(.*(?:\R(?!\p{Lu}+\h).*)*)~mu';
preg_match_all($re, $s, $m);
$result = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [ОБАНДОМ] => آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукан- дом, латифбадан.
    [FБАФКАН] => آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, даст- гоњи обпошї.
    [БАНЉИР] => انجير آب обе, ки дар он анљири ќоќ
ва хушкро мељӯшонанд ва он хусусияти
табобатї дорад.
    [ӮББАДАЛ] => بدل آب муовизаи об, табдили об.
)
```

You may "shrink" the line breaks using

```
$result = array_combine($m[1], preg_replace('~\s*\R\s*~u', ' ', $m[2]));
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/d2Yjou). The `\s*\R\s*` pattern matches any 0+ whitespaces followed with an obligatory line break sequence followed with any 0+ whitespaces, and replaces the matches with  a regular space.

The second array can easily be built by removing all the non-Arabic chars from the description values:

```
$second = array_combine($m[1], preg_replace('~\P{Arabic}+~u', '', $m[2]));
print_r($second);
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/UXBlJ2.).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can be get second result array `$wordsTranslate` from first result? I think it's possible. For example, all the letters (a-yA-Ya-zA-z) and the symbols from the string must be deleted. Can I then get the second outcome? Or on another it is made? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: And your answer has one drawback when you delete the transfer which is in the text. For example, you have the following line in your answer: `нозукан- дом` or `даст- гоњи`. And they are moving lines that should have merged after removing hyphens. That is, the rezestat would be like this:`нозукандом` or `дастгоњи` @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @Otabek `нозукан- дом` issue cannot be handled with 1 regex, there is no guarantee that `нозукан-дом` is not a valid compound word. If there cannot be hyphenated words, just remove all `-` between words with `preg_replace('~\b- \b~u', '', $vals)`.

Comment: And that's why I used this code: `preg_replace('~-\R~', '', $text);` I think that before the task is done, you must first delete the symbol - and combine the words and then execute your code. And what do you think about getting the second result of the array as mentioned and shown above? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @Otabek I added the code, see https://ideone.com/UXBlJ2, `preg_replace('~\P{Arabic}+~u', '', $m[2])` will remove all non-Arabic chars from descriptions.

Comment: Ok, thanks working. But test this string for first array result: `ТББАНД بند آب 1. он ки дар пеши об банд ё
дарѓот месозад. 2. банд, дарѓот.` Here, the number 1 is moved before the Arabic symbol.

Comment: How do I add a regular expression to the first result to delete Arabic characters? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Well, I am not already sure what you mean: try https://ideone.com/EtDsRx to get the first Arabic word followed with 0+ sequences of whitespaces and Arabic words after.

Comment: I looked at your code but I think that the result I need is not possible to receive. You'll see by deleting the `"ТББАНД"` line from this line `("ТББАНД بند آب 1. он ки дар пеши об банд ё дарѓот месозад. 2. банд, дарѓот.")` And see the change in the line. As you see the `Arabic` words here before the number `"1"` and when we delete the row `"ТББАНД"` number `"1"` is moved `before` the Arabic symbol.

Comment: The final test, how to remove from the string Arabic words or symbols for the first result? Example now your result so: `[ӮББАДАЛ] => بدل آب муовизаи об, табдили об.` and I must delete here arabic letters and get so result: `[ӮББАДАЛ] => муовизаи об, табдили об.` @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: To remove all Arabic chars just use `preg_replace('/\p{Arabic}+/u', '',$arr)`

Comment: Thanks for fully answering @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: As I see, not so fully. See https://regex101.com/r/ZkClYi/1 about how to remove `-` between parts of words.

Comment: Why? ;) @Wiktor Stribiżew. Because of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852467/how-to-combine-the-separation-of-a-word-in-the-text)?

Comment: Sure, it is a follow up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157177/discussion-between-otabek-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Hello @Wiktor Stribiżew. There are tasks that concern this type of text which I do not want to solve myself. Can I expand this issue and add those tasks to the same issue? Or create a new question instead?

Comment: You may ask a new question if it is not related to splitting text into parts.

Comment: Ok @Wiktor Stribiżew. I'm now preparing a big question, look then someday if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

Your could try this regex [`\b([Ѐ-ЯҐ-ҲFӮҶӢ]+)(.+?)(?:\n(?=[Ѐ-ЯҐ-ҲFӮҶӢ])|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/oIuR78/1) in PHP script:

```
$str = "ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукан- дом, латифбадан.
FБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, даст- гоњи обпошї.
БАНЉИР انجير آب обе, ки дар он анљири ќоќ
ва хушкро мељӯшонанд ва он хусусияти
табобатї дорад.
ӮББАДАЛ بدل آب муовизаи об, табдили об.";

preg_match_all('/\b([Ѐ-ЯҐ-ҲFӮҶӢ]+)(.+?)(?:\n(?=[Ѐ-ЯҐ-ҲFӮҶӢ])|$)/us', 
               $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $m)
  $dict[$m[1]] = $m[2];

var_dump($dict);
```

Comment: This is very resource consuming, [it takes 6773 steps](https://regex101.com/r/oIuR78/1) while [mine takes just 433](https://regex101.com/r/diLvEz/2) (more than 12 times as ~"fast").

Comment: Indeed, my solution is slower than yours. But ... still if author is building dictionary keys just for one language and not for all - my solution would be more correct than yours, because I try to match letters from one language alphabet, and you match ALL unicode letters which may or may be not acceptable by author. Problem is that I couldn't exactly deduce what language is used for keys - [whatlanguageisthis.com](http://whatlanguageisthis.com/) reports that it is Serbian. But i'm not sure. And some language chars are spread across all unicode table - another problem for char range matching

Comment: my expression is more precise because the uppercase letters are only matched at the start of the line. You used `\b` word boundary, that may match these letters anywhere inside the line. Google says it is Tajik, btw. If OP confirms they only need to match Tajik (Cyrillic) uppercase letters, it won't be a big problem to create a range for them, maybe you guessed the range right.

Comment: I've used `\b` because I needed `$` to match end of input instead of end of line in multiline `#m` mode as in yours. I don't believe in everything that google says. Language detection is not an easy task. Here answer is ["language":"tg","isReliable":false,"confidence":11.6](https://detectlanguage.com/). So confidence is low that this is Tajik language. To have a high confidence you need to feed a big block of text in that language to algorithm and also have good statistics data (bigram,trigram frequencies for that language to be able to guess it correctly)