# How to combine the separation of a word in the text?

Tags: php, regex

I've simple text:

```
$text = "БАДРЎ(Й) (ي(بدرو он ки рўи нозебу хунук до-
рад, бадафт, безеб, бадбашара; муќоб. Тез-тез зур - зур.
ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукан- дом, латифбадан.
FБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, даст- гоњи обпошї.";
```

Here I want to combine words and get this result:

БАДРЎ(Й) (ي(بدرو он ки рўи нозебу хунук **дорад**, бадафт, безеб, бадбашара; муќоб. Тез-тез ганда. ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, **нозукандом**, латифбадан.
FБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики зур - зур обафкан, **дастгоњи** обпошї.

That is, you need to combine these words in this way:

**до-
рад** to **дорад**

**нозукан- дом** to **нозукандом**

**даст- гоњи** to **дастгоњи**

I use this code for deleting \r\n:

```
$regex = '~-\R~';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
```

And get only that result:

БАДРЎ(Й) (ي(بدرو он ки рўи нозебу хунук **дорад**, бадафт, безеб, бадбашара; муќоб. Тез-тез зур - зур. ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукан- дом, латифбадан. FБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, даст- гоњи обпошї.

Could not combine these words:

**нозукан- дом** to **нозукандом**

**даст- гоњи** to **дастгоњи**

Comment: Try [`$result = preg_replace('~\b-(?:\R|\h)\b~u', '', $string);`](https://regex101.com/r/ZkClYi/2)

Comment: Thanks for all for answering. Which response code works faster? I wish a comparative-review.

Comment: I'd rather worry about the regex precision in this case rather than speed

Comment: Yes, as @WiktorStribiżew suggested, make some test case and run all the regex on them, look for which is more precise.

Comment: Working only you '@Wiktor Stribiżew' answer and answer '@ishegg' correctly

Comment: Note that `\h` matches any horizontal whitespace. Even a tab.

Comment: Your work is faster in my opinion, but you did not answer how to answer the question. @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @Otabek Ok, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
$result = preg_replace('~\b-(?:\R|\h)\b~u', '', $string);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZkClYi/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (the current position must be preceded with a word char
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?:\R|\h)` - a line break sequence (`\R`) or (`|`) any horizontal whitespace (`\h`)
- `\b` - a word boundary (there must be a word char immediately to the right of the current location)

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/RuFE84):

```
$string = "БАДРЎ(Й) (ي(بدرو он ки рўи нозебу хунук до-
рад, бадафт, безеб, бадбашара; муќоб. Тез-тез зур - зур.
ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукан- дом, латифбадан.
FБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, даст- гоњи обпошї.";
$result = preg_replace('~\b-(?:\R|\h)\b~u', '', $string);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
БАДРЎ(Й) (ي(بدرو он ки рўи нозебу хунук дорад, бадафт, безеб, бадбашара; муќоб. Тез-тез зур - зур.
ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукандом, латифбадан.
FБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, дастгоњи обпошї.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex:

```
preg_replace("/((?<![ ])[-][ \r\n]+)/", '', $text)
```

this will match those words just fine. [Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/xAzE5l/3)

Comment: Thanks for answering but you code combain this word `Тез-тез` to `Тезтез`

Comment: Thanks working! :) And now we need to compare whose code is faster. Yours or another.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace either `\R` or a space, and add word boundaries (`\b`). Lastly, since you're now dealing with words, you need to add the [`u` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) so the engine considers UTF-8.

```
<?php
$text = "БАДРЎ(Й) (ي(بدرو он ки рўи нозебу хунук до-
рад, бадафт, безеб, бадбашара; муќоб. Тез-тез зур - зур.
ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукан- дом, латифбадан.
FБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, даст- гоњи обпошї.";
$regex = '/\b-(\R| )\b/u';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '', $text);
echo $result;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/EhLpU)

**Result**:

> БАДРЎ(Й) (ي(بدرو он ки рўи нозебу хунук дорад, бадафт, безеб, бадбашара; муќоб. Тез-тез зур - зур.
>   ОБАНДОМ آباندام маљ. обпайкар, нозукандом, латифбадан.
>   FБАФКАН آبافكن муњаррики обафкан, дастгоњи обпошї.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a couple of those are not at the endlines, right? So you might need to also include:

```
$regex = '~- ~';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
```

And I don't have the ability to test this, but you could possibly combine the two with

```
$regex = '~-(\R| )~';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
```

Comment: It works but is slightly incorrect. You do not need to delete a "-" in this word: `зур - зур`